How to achieve this ripple effect in vector?

How can I achieve this ripple (doppler) effect in Adobe Illustrator? I currently have a black canvas with white horizontal lines. From here, what are the steps? And I would really like to be able to dial the ripples up or down (number of waves and amplitude), if possible.
For reference, I found the image here: https://www.behance.net/gallery/135440721/Doppler-effect
Some of the math used to create these doppler effects are listed there.

This type of distortion is simply not easily created with Adobe Illustrator.

The image doesn't present by any means Doppler's frequency shift effect nor doctor Doppler himself. The connection between the image and dr. Doppler's works is an artistic decision. The shown example is a decorated stop motion image of a circularly symmetric transversal displacement wave on a plane surface. We can think it's the XY-plane which starts to get bent.  The source of the wave is a point in the middle of the image (=XYZ origin). The source point is forced to oscillate sinusoidally along the z-axis. The decoration: alternating black and white equally wide straight stripes painted onto the oscillating surface (before the oscillation was started). The stripes are stretched and squeezed following the surface is deformation caused by the propagating wave.
To make the image as vector drawing in Illustrator is far from trivial. Some options:

Draw it. It's not easy but it's surely possible to trace it from the example photo. Even automatic tracing can create a result which is good enough for something. Using it legally is totally another problem, because it's a copy - no matter you perhaps drew it manually.

Write a (complex) script which draws it by starting from the equations of the described wave motion and the decoration pattern. The equations should be written for the bent surface+decoration pattern and  the wanted 2D view. I guess very few of the users of this site have the skills to program the needed script. But the method makes possible to change the parameters and even to generate an animation (=a series of images)

Use a 3D program and generate there the bent surface and the decoration pattern on it. Extract the wanted view of it as vector and open it in Illustrator to change colors and insert other artwork items. If the 3D program can be controlled with math formulas or it at least builds a structure tree (like professional 3D CAD programs) you can generate the varied versions quite easily after making one.


Creating a single static version by using method 3 looks easy enough for me. Illustrator itself could create the bent surface. 3D effect Revolve makes it perfectly. But I have not found a way to map the decorative pattern on it without getting a heavy polar coordinate distortion. To avoid it I must make the surface and map the pattern in another program. Fortunately this doesn't need any complex nor high cost package - simplest 3D CAD programs are enough. The program must use spline based surfaces and be able to export views as vectors which can be opened in Illustrator. That, of course, rules out 3D programs where all surfaces are polygon meshes.
The next image has a manually drawn XZ plane spline curve in a 3D program. The curve is a rough approximation of a sinusoidal curve:

The curve is revolved to a surface:

An array of straight lines is inserted above the surface to generate the decorative pattern:

The lines are projected straight downwards on the surface. Original lines are hidden:

The view angle is adjusted a little less tilted, the view is exported as PDF and opened in Illustrator:

The export was done as "curves only" because the rendered image of the surface is a bitmap.
In the next image the areas are filled with the shape builder and the strokes are removed. Fill colors are pink and black. Pink is used to make contrast against the white background:

It was simple, but the amount of needed knowledge surely jumps if you want parametric version or animation.
